# How to disable / avoid shimming of createEvent by Google Cast sender api on iOS Chrome?

Tags: reactjs, google-cast

This might be a bizarrely specific issue, but I'm hoping someone else has seen something similar.

In short, it seems like when importing the Google Cast Chrome Sender API library into my react application, core dom functions that react relies on such as event creation start throwing errors causing state refreshes, clicks and other events to not be processed.

It looks like certain core DOM functions (notably `document.createElement`) are being replaced in ways that are incompatible with use of react.js. I'm only seeing this on iOS chrome. Loading the same page in android chrome or iOS safari doesn't seem to show this issue.

I can't find any reference to this behaviour, it seems to just be an implementation detail (I'm guessing shimming to enable something). I'm at a loss on how to make the combination of react and casting work in iOS chrome and would really appreciate any new avenues of investigation.

This issue is not entirely consistent, so there's some race condition going on. But I find if I refresh a few times it happens fairly consistently.

I've created a [minimal reproduction of the issue](https://github.com/orthanc/issue-reproduction-react-vs-cast-sending), a more detailed description is below.

*The Setup*
I have a very simple react application created using the [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-new-app.html) tool.

The relevant parts of the App are shown below, but in short, it has a clickable div that triggers an alert, and a 5 second timer to show a second clickable div by changing state:

```
function onClick() {
  alert('clicked');
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    setTimeout(this.show, 5000);
  }

  show = () => {
    let evt = document.createEvent('event');
    alert(evt);
    this.setState({
      show: true
    });
  }
  render() {
    let link2 = this.state.show ? <div onClick={onClick}>Click Here</div> : null;
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <div onClick={onClick}>Click Here</div>
          <hr/>
          {link2}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This works as expected. However, when I import the google cast sender API into the HTML page as recommended in the [getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender_integrate#wzxhzdk30wzxhzdk31load_the_library) I start seeing 2 problems on iOS Chrome.

1. Clicking the div's doesn't trigger the alert.
2. When the state change fires, the following error is shown

> TypeError: Argument 1 ('event') to EventTarget.dispatchEvent must be an instance of Event

This error seems to be thrown from deep within the react code:

```
invokeGuardedCallbackDev
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:581
  578 | // errors, it will trigger our global error handler.
  579 | var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
  580 | evt.initEvent(evtType, false, false);
> 581 | fakeNode.dispatchEvent(evt);
  582 | 
  583 | if (didError) {
  584 |   if (!didSetError) {
```

My theory is the same error is being thrown on the click events, but being hidden since it's not triggered by user code, which would explain the non-functioning clicks.

I've done a bit of debugging, and it seems that when I don't import the google cast sender API the `document.createEvent` function returns Events, where as when I'm importing the cast sender API it returns objects.

I've also confirmed that the function is being swapped out somewhere between the initial page load and this call by backing up the `createEvent` function and then comparing it to `document.createEvent` immediately before the `setState` call.

I've also used a timeout to restore the `createElement` function from a backup after it's swapped out. This seems to fix the internal react event, however I then get further failures due to other functions related to Node creation being shimmed in a similar manner.

This is visible with iOS Chrome Version:

```
Google Chrome 64.0.3282.112 (Official Build) stable (64-bit)
Revision  7ceafc6ca46e012a6dbb5933d52fae00eda1f3ca-refs/branch-heads/3282@{#576}
OS  iOS
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 11_2_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/64.0.3282.112 Mobile/15D60 Safari/604.1
```

This behaviour doesn't exhibit on android chrome.

Does anyone have any idea how this could be worked around so I can use both react.js and google cast sending in iOS Chrome?

Comment: Hi, I've stumbled upon the same issue! Unfortunately, I don't have a solution, but for now I've bypassed this issue by removing the cast sdk on iOS devices.